# How to think about this moment from BWV 816

Tags: harmony, analysis, counterpoint, modulation, j-s-bach

I've been tasked by a textbook I'm going through to make a harmonic analysis of the G major "Gavotte" from BWV816, "The French Suite" specifically minding a handful of questions regarding how the piece modulates. Arriving at bar 17, the B section — having charted some fairly standard common-chord-modulations either to the relative E minor or D Major — I halt at the introduction of F natural, wondering how to view its significance.

As I see it, bar 17 begins on a G chord, seemingly establishing the key of G instead of Em again, which the prior phrase cadences on. What of the F naturals though, first the one that the bass line skirts by, and then the first note of the upper line, bar 18?

Would one consider this a secondary dominant harmony: G7 to a very brief C major decorated with a "sus - 4 - sus 2 - 3"-pattern? (I.e. a very short-lived modulation, I suppose?). Or is it better viewed just as the key of G taking a "mixolydian"-like F natural in order to fulfill some contrapuntal/linear concerns that have been developing in the piece? I realize this is probably a matter open to interpretation, I'm just interested in what may perhaps be learned from the weighting of various interpretations.

(I should add that, with how quickly this piece progresses in a typical recording, I find it quite hard hearing a "G dominant to C" moment being borne out, in the heat of the moment — even with intent repeat listening. But that might just be par for the course with this kind of contrapuntal texture and tempo.)

Audio with notation (timed to Gavotte m. 9 -- start of B section):

Sheet music:
[image: BWV 816 Score]

Answer (score 2):

your first thought about bar 17 is correct - it's the secondary dominant of chord IV (it doesn't *modulate* to C major).

The underlying chord sequence is a bit obscured by the figuration and the avoidance of 'problems', but line 1 below shows the origin of these bars.

Line 2 shows what happens when we decorate the bass line to include the ascending and descending scales. It creates two issues. Firstly, the f-natural in the melody doubles the left hand, stressing the tritone with the b-natural. Secondly it makes the V7 chord seem like it's in second inversion, which Bach's training would have led him to avoid in a situation like this.

Line 3 shows how Bach delays the melodic f-natural, making it an accented passing note. The 'second inversion' chord V7 is 'fixed' through not having the d in the melody at that point (as if it was going to be chord VII - a standard trick when facing an unwanted second inversion), echoing instead the characteristic upbeat figure that we've heard all through the piece. The b-natural in bar 19 was not used in the end; d-natural was instead. Why? If you try the right hand figuration in the second half of bar 19 starting on the b-natural you'll get parallel octaves with the rising left hand.

As to the exact route by which *Bach himself* got there...we'll never know, but these types of obscured ancestral chord patterns, along with glimpses of problem solving, are typical of his style.

[image]

Generally, I would avoid thinking in terms of mixolydian or other modes for Bach. Modes were a historical relic fifty years before Bach was born and it was over a hundred years after he died before they became interesting again. There are so-called 'modal chorales' but this refers to the original chorale melodies, which are rather vexing to harmonise tonally (which is what Bach did).

Comment: Oh, that is quite interesting. I suppose that points to the F in bar 17 really being "meant", then, as a harmonic component, on that account of the origin of the F beginning the 18th bar, right hand.

"Avoidance of problems" definitely could be part of what I was trying to get at with "contrapuntal/linear concerns. (I suppose that I could have arrived at bar 17 myself, from my limited perspective, by modifying the F# simply to avoid the tritone with C, not looking for anything other than I - IV but taking the secondary dominant as it appeared — a thought.)

Comment: (And, no, I didn't mean much of "mixolydian" — I could just as well have been speaking of a major scale with a flattened seventh centered on any other note than G)

Answer (score 1):

Allowing, as you say, this is a matter of interpretation, here's mine:

At the beginning of measure 17, there is a clear arrival in G major. The second half of that measure, along with the first half of measure 18, tonicize C major -- the pre-dominant key relative to G major -- before moving to D7 -- the dominant -- in the second half of measure 18. From there on, the piece generally expresses the D7 until the final cadence in G major.

When played at speed, the C major tonicization works well, but when played slowly, the F natural in measure 17 really does sound like G mixolydian. The F in measure 18 makes more sense at either speed.

In the big picture, measures 9 - 16 are the "development" section, where Bach takes us on a tour through a few different keys, and measure 17 is the beginning of the re-establishment of G major.

[image: BWV 816 mm. 17-end analysis]

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thank you. Thinking about "tonicization" in general, and looking specifically at the second half of measure 17, I suppose I could see an F major chord in there as well. Regardless, a brief tour by C major.

Comment: We could say the music has modulated to Em by bar 16.   There's nothing worthy of the label 'modulation' in 17 - 18.

Comment: No, agreed. It has stuck with me from somewhere and somewhere, I think, where the (normal) resolution of a secondary dominant was conceptually framed as "kind of" modulation, of the smallest, shortest order. But I can see how this would go in direction of an unhelpful conflation of what is productively separated terminology, in "tonicization" on one hand and "modulation" on other.